# A 60’s or earlier short story about time travel and a dinosaur hunt that changes the present

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

It is a short story, which I read in the '60s but might be older. 
This story is neither ["Big Game"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Game_(short_story)) nor ["Day of the Hunters"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_of_the_Hunters). It *might* still be by Asimov, but I doubt it. Two stories on the same topic, OK, but three?

It is not "Deathbeast" either, I just saw that one in the "box" that opened when I entered the title of my question, and I checked, it does not fit.

In this story, time travel exists and there is a company that takes hunters to the past to kill dinosaurs. However they are extremely careful to do nothing in the past that might affect their present.
Once something wrong happens. Maybe it was an accident, but I think one of the hunters did something he was not supposed to do. The guy from the company tries very hard to correct the problem. But when he gets back to his present he realises something is wrong. He has missed some small detail and the present has changed. And in a seriously bad way.

Comment: Since the OP of the question with the butterfly had accepted the same answer, mine is indeed a duplicate. But that one did not open in the "box", only the one with the answer "Deathbeast"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably *A Sound of Thunder* by Ray Bradbury

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Sound_of_Thunder

> Upon returning to 2055, Eckels notices subtle changes – English words are now spelled and spoken strangely, people behave differently, and Eckels discovers that Deutscher has won the election instead of Keith. Looking at the mud on his boots, Eckels finds a crushed butterfly, whose death has apparently caused a rift in the timeline that has affected the nature of the alternative present to which the safari has returned. He frantically pleads with Travis to take him back into the past to undo the damage, but Travis had previously explained that the time machine cannot return to any point in time that it has already visited (so as to prevent any paradoxes). Travis raises his gun, and there is "a sound of thunder."